# Java Concurrent API Work-Stealing Algorithm

Tags: java

What is Java concurrent API's Work-Stealing algorithm?

How Java concurrent API's Work-Stealing algorithm for its task works internally by JVM?

Comment: Did you even try to google that first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is Java concurrent API's Work-Stealing algorithm?

I think you are referring to the Fork / Join framework.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

> How Java concurrent API's Work-Stealing algorithm for its task works internally by JVM?

It is too much to ask someone to provide a full explanation in a answer. However, you can read the source-code of `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool` to find out.  Google for `"ForkJoinPool source"` to find it on the web.

(There is a long "Implementation Overview" comment near the start of the source file.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions sure i will read and look in to it.